# How often does `grub.cfg` change?

Tags: boot, grub2

I made a cron job to back up `grub.cfg` weekly, so I can see for myself, but I'll have to wait for a while before I can actually check.

Assuming I don't change files like `/etc/default/grub`, and I don't make changes to partitions and stuff, what will change? Will anything change besides the `linux` and `initrd` lines?

Comment: On Fedora it rarely if ever changes because Fedora's GRUB populates kernel entries automatically thanks to `BLSCFG` https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/BootLoaderSpecByDefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu, `grub.cfg` is only changed whenever a new kernel is installed. Please note that some update processes run `update-grub` just to be on the safe side, but the resulting file will have the same contents.

Most distributions offer a more fancy GRUB configuration with menu entries, additional functionality such as entering the EFI Setup or booting other operating systems or kernels. The entire configuration is re-written, but the effective changes (as in "what is booted at the end of the day") are indeed most often limited to the `linux` and `initrd` lines.

There are other situations where the `grub.cfg` must be adjusted. In case you would ever change your root partition's identifier. In ancient times, the device name (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) was used. Nowadays, the UUID is used and you would only change that explicitly manually if you really have to. Sometimes, the LABEL is used, but that is rare.